# Add css class to dropdown menu on menu item click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bootstrap 3 menu. And I want to add class to "dropdown" menu if usre click on "caret" ( parent menu item )

```
<ul id="menu-testing-menu" class="nav navbar-nav sf-js-enabled" style="touch-action: pan-y;">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown">
        <a class="sf-with-ul" data-toggle="dropdown">Home<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="#">Lorem Ipdum</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="#">Lorem Ipdum</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="#">Lorem Ipdum</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So I try to use js

```
$('#menu-testing-menu li a .caret').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('dd-menu-show');
});
```

but it doesn't work. How to solve thise problem?

Comment: You also need to $(this).parent().find(); as dropdown menu is not inside a

Comment: @abhishekkannojia incorrect, the `.caret` class is on the `span` element inside the `a`.

Comment: @ChemicalRocketeer Oh my bad! Thought it was on same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).find('.dropdown-menu')` is not possible when clicking `.caret` because `$(this)` is looking inside the current element and it is empty.

You might also want to consider adding the click event to the entire `<a>`.

Try this

```
$('#menu-testing-menu li a .caret').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var parent = $(this).closest('.dropdown');
  parent.find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('dd-menu-show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` searches for a node inside the selected node. You are selecting the `.caret` span element, so it's trying to find a `.dropdown-menu` node inside that, which of course does not exist. You'll want to navigate up the tree to the `.dropdown` node, and then do your `find()` call.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find(".dropdown-menu")` will not work because there is no element in the current clicked element with class `dropdown-menu`.
So just try :

```
$('#menu-testing-menu li a .caret').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('dd-menu-show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way.

```
$('#menu-testing-menu li a .caret').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().next('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('dd-menu-show');
});
```